# Play sound with ringtone stream

Tags: android

How can I play a song (about 3 minutes) using the ringtone or notification stream? I tried this:

```
MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create (this,R.raw.a);
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```

But then I got the message that this isn't available. How can I play a song via this stream? And is it possible to play a song via `STREAM_MUSIC` at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

```
int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
mediaPlayer.start();
```